# iOS Open PDF file in another application

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I would like to share/open the PDF files in my app in another application.

The two main apps I would like to share with are Dropbox & PDF Expert.

This is the code I was using but it is not working. For example, if I try to share the file via airdrop, email and WhatsApp it doesn't share anything

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", @"test"]];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath];
NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:URL, nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

test.pdf file is in my project.

If there is a way to share PDFs from a server? It would be better so I would not need to download the file in my app and then share it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
// In your header. MyViewController.h
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController 
                              <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
{
UIDocumentInteractionController *docController;
}

// In your implementation. MyViewController.m Open Results is hooked up 
to a button.
- (void)openResults
{
 // Generate PDF Data.
 NSData *pdfData = [self makePDF];

 // Create a filePath for the pdf.
 NSArray *paths = 
 NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
 NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory 
 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Report.pdf"];

 // Save the PDF. UIDocumentInteractionController has to use a physical 
 PDF, not just the data.
 [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

 // Open the controller.
 docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController 
 interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
 docController.delegate = self;
 docController.UTI = @"com.adobe.pdf";
 [docController presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:shareButton 
 animated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for he reply, But your code is missing the makePDF and shareButton. Can u please add them